# How do I write Ansible task for 'systemctl set-default graphical.target' without shell/command modules

Tags: ansible

I want to write a task in Ansible to perform the following command:

"systemctl set-default graphical.target" without using shell/command modules.

not sure that the "ansible.builtin.systemd" module has this option.

Comment: There is an openned ticket for that: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/65785

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you execute `systemctl set-default graphical.target` you can see this log

```
Removed symlink /etc/systemd/system/default.target. 
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/default.target to /usr/lib/systemd/system/graphical.target.
```

Then you can use `file` module to create symlink as below

```
- name: Change default target
  hosts: all
  become: yes
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
  - name: Change default target to graphical.target
    file:
      src: /usr/lib/systemd/system/graphical.target
      dest: /etc/systemd/system/default.target
      state: link
```

Comment: On a Debian system the target files are stored in: /lib/systemd/system/ - is there a way of knowing where the directory for the targets are without hard-coding it?

Comment: This is a bad solution. It uses the implementation details and is distro specific. I don't understand why this is the excepted answer. It would be much better to use the "frontend" itself. Call systemctl get-default in Ansible and register the output. When the output contains not graphical, then call a second command with systemctl set-default. This works on all distributions

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `command` module and use some when magic magic to have an idempotent solution for your problem. Actually there is no concrete module and the given [change request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/65785) for the systemd module was closed and is not merged.

```yaml
- name: "Get current systemd default" # noqa: command-instead-of-module
  ansible.builtin.command: "systemctl get-default"
  changed_when: false
  register: systemdefault
    
- name: "Set default to graphical target"
  ansible.builtin.command: "systemctl set-default graphical.target"
  when: "'graphical' not in systemdefault.stdout"
  changed_when: true
```

Of course this uses command. But there is no bad reason to not use command when you know, when you need to use it. It doesn't look nice  - ok. But at the end a custom module would also do the same under the hood and it could be a little bit to complex for such a "single" problem. Actually the "link" solution does the same, but its necessary to explicitly know the location of the link files (see Debian).

Answer (score 0):

[@njh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1156096/njh) I just spotted this when looking for something else. `/lib/systemd` contains the systemd files installed with APT, etc., local overrides are in `/etc/systemd`, which includes the default target, so if you want to change the default target, change the symlink as [@gary-lopez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12008179/gary-lopez) suggests.

```
Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Sat Oct 23 20:00:36 2021 from 192.168.1.10
pi@penguin:~ $ ls -l /etc/systemd/system/default.target 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 Feb 13  2020 /etc/systemd/system/default.target -> /lib/systemd/system/graphical.target
pi@penguin:~ $ ls -l /lib/systemd/system/default.target
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Aug  6 17:38 /lib/systemd/system/default.target -> graphical.target
pi@penguin:~ $
```

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
- name: Make sure, the graphical.target unit is the default.
  vars:
    cmdCheck: systemctl get-default | grep -q ^graphical.target$
    cmdSet: systemctl set-default graphical.target
  ansible.builtin.shell:
    cmd: '{{ cmdCheck }} && exit 0; {{ cmdSet }}; {{ cmdCheck }} && exit 1; exit 2'
  register: _
  changed_when: _.rc == 1
  failed_when: _.rc == 2
```

if you want to make sure, in addition, that the graphical.target is active:

```
- name: Make sure, the graphical.target unit is active.
  vars:
    cmdCheck: systemctl status graphical.target
    cmdSet: systemctl isolate graphical.target
  ansible.builtin.shell:
    cmd: '{{ cmdCheck }} && exit 0; {{ cmdSet }}; {{ cmdCheck }} && exit 1; exit 2'
  register: _
  changed_when: _.rc == 1
  failed_when: _.rc == 2
```